# How can I write all JS files to one single html page?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

I have a html page and inside of it there are 4 script tags with "src" attribute.I mean that there are 4 more JS files.I want to write all codes in src files between script tags and want to reach all content from one single HTML page .

How can I write all JS files content to one single HTML page ?

Comment: and why is the question tagged as C#4.0 ?

Comment: May be by implying the reason you want to this would help ppl give better answers and even better options for you. what do u think @erdem-gundogdu

Comment: im doing this on asp.net,i can get results but my prof wants a single html page,not a asp.net project,wants to copy the html and get the results on another computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the content via AJAX as "text", then push it into the DOM (I'm using jQuery, but you can use anything similar):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "file1.js",
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data){
    $('head').append('<script>' + data + '</script>')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have just a html page with inline js code?

if that is the case you may want to write your javascript code between "script" tags inline in html without specifying an external file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('Hello World!') ;
</script>
```

Comment: i tried it but didnt work,i have many comment lines within the JS files,possibly it's the reason ,what do you think ?

Comment: can we have your js files? the comments should not be the problem. where do you put that "script" tag? in the `<head>` or `<body>` ?

Comment: in the <head> . actually i downloaded them from a site to make charts,they are its JS files,and all comments are with "//",i guess it's the problem but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit like you are trying to 'minify' and combine your JS sources (I could be wrong, if so sorry).  You might want to take a look at:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/